# How to transfer function value to thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I want to transfer the text to thymeleaf, so that depending on the value of the function in verificationPage the text is displayed

```
public String activate(Map<String, String> model, @PathVariable String code) {
    boolean isActivated = userService.activateUser(code);
    // TODO: change to boolean in template
    if (isActivated) {
        model.put("message", "User Successfully activated");
    } else model.put("message", "Activation code not found");
    return "verificationPage";
}
```

the value of the message in the function will not be, I transferred to the template, but I don’t know how to take the value of this function, that is, true or false to understand which message to show

```
<div th:if="${#bools.isTrue(message)}"><p>User Successfully activated .</p></div>
<div th:unless="${#bools.isFalse(message)}"><p>Activation code not found.</p></div>
```

How to transfer function value to thymeleaf?

```
public String processForgotPasswordForm(@RequestBody User userData) throws Exception {
    User dbUser;
    String userEmail = userData.getEmail();
    String userName = userData.getUsername();
    if (userEmail == null && userName == null) {
        throw new Exception("Пустое поле");
    }
    if (userEmail != null) {
        dbUser = userService.findUserByEmail(userEmail);
    } else {
            dbUser = userService.findUserByUsername(userName);
    }

    if (dbUser != null) {
        String newPassword = RandomStringUtils.randomAlphanumeric(8);
        String hashPass = DigestUtils.md5Hex(newPassword);
        dbUser.setValidatyTime(new Date());
        dbUser.setTemporaryPassword(hashPass);
        userService.save(dbUser);
        // TODO: move to template
        String message = String.format(
                "Your new temporary password, which will be valid for an hour " + " " + newPassword + "\nYou can log in and change your password to a new one.\n");
        mailSenderService.send(dbUser.getEmail(), "Temporary password", message);
    }
    return "wait";

}
```

also with the message here, but another template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you to send `true` or `false` value through controller

```
public String activate(Map<String, String> model, @PathVariable String code) {
    boolean isActivated = userService.activateUser(code);
    // TODO: change to boolean in template
    if (isActivated) {
        model.put("message", "User Successfully activated");
    } else model.put("message", "Activation code not found");
     model.put("isActivated", isActivated);

    return "verificationPage";
}
```

And in the html you can try

```
<div  th:if="${isActivated} == true"><p>User Successfully activated .</p></div>
<div th:unless="${isActivated}"><p>Activation code not found.</p></div>
```

**Updated**`

In your case you can just print message alone you dont need to have`if`condition at all.

```
<div ><p>${message}</p></div>
```

Comment: i shound not use if (isActivated) {
        model.put("message", "User Successfully activated");
    } else model.put("message", "Activation code not found");
     model.put("isActivated", isActivated); ?

Comment: You can do that. It is just a matter of style to define messages in templates. If you wanna change a message you naturally tend to change the template and not the controller. That's different if you are using the message resolver (then you are defining messages in property-files).

Comment: public ModelAndView activate(Map<String, String> model, @PathVariable String code) {
        boolean isActivated = userService.activateUser(code);
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("verificationPage");
        return modelAndView;
    }

Comment: i cant transfer value of isActivated(

Comment: Still you didn't send the boolean value.Do `modelAndView .put("isActivated", isActivated)` along with viewname

Comment: but the option that you advised does not work either, I want without modelandview

Comment: Are you ok with checking message value then ?You must understand that whatever value you are sending through controller those values only can access .

Comment: You dont want if or unless just directly print the message whatsoever

Comment: Can you comment the second case?

Comment: i want to transfer mail message in template

Comment: I can't see where you are getting the message in mail . is it part of `userdata`?

Comment: private JavaMailSender mailSender;
    @Value("${spring.mail.username}")
    private String username;
    public void sendEmail(SimpleMailMessage email) {
        mailSender.send(email);
    }

    public void send(String emailTo, String subject, String message){
        SimpleMailMessage mailMessage = new SimpleMailMessage();

        mailMessage.setFrom(username);
        mailMessage.setTo(emailTo);
        mailMessage.setSubject(subject);
        mailMessage.setText(message);
        mailSender.send(mailMessage);
    }

Comment: Please update in the question or create a new question it easy to sorted out.

Comment: can we connect in telegram?

Comment: i cant create new question

Comment: @samir you can Update the question . comment if you add i can't fully understand the code.